# Scala REPL hangs while running factorial

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I stumbed on the link below which shows how funny scala messages can be ;)

[Scala REPL "She's gone rogue" error message](http://www.devdaily.com/scala/funny-scala-repl-shes-gone-rogue-captain-error-message)

When i tried this example, it hung forever.what is happening here?

Is this a known bug?Is it some kind of gotcha?

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_29
).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> def factorial(n: Int):Int = {
     |   if (n == 1) n    // forgot 'return' here
     |   factorial(n - 1)
     | }
factorial: (n: Int)Int

scala> factorial(10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is exactly what is indicated in the code, `return` is missing. The recursion never terminates.

`factorial(n - 1)` is not connected to the  `if` statement in any way. This means, that it executes unconditionally. `factorial()` wil *always* call itself.

Adding a base case (i.e. where the recursion stops):

```
def factorial(n: Int):Int = {
     |   if (n == 1) return n
     |   factorial(n - 1)
     | }
```

This would work as well:

```
def factorial(n: Int):Int = {
     |   if (n == 1) n
     |   else factorial(n - 1)
     | }
```

This will actually produce the factorial of n (the others return 1):

```
def factorial(n: Int):Int = {
     |   if (n <= 1) 1
     |   else n * factorial(n - 1)
     | }
```

Note that this works for the case `n = 0` correctly as well. It still accepts negative numbers, however.

Comment: so is this a programming mistake?

Comment: @SantoshGokak: Yes. The recursion is missing a so-called "base case".

Comment: Even with the fix, it's not a correct factorial function though.  It in fact just always returns 1.